# Arithmetic mean of the length of tangents to a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

> There are eight circles $S (i = 1,2,3,.....8)$ of radius $1,2,3.......8$ respectively and all the circles are passing through $(8,8)$ and $(9,9)$ then the arithmetic mean of the length of tangents drawn from $(0,0)$ to these circles is:
> A)$12$
> B)$6$
> C)$3$
> D)$1$

What I have tried:

[image]

As the length of $PQ$ is smaller than all the diameters, it must be a chord.
Now by parametric equation, the coordinates of $B(x_1,y_1)$ can be found out as:
$$\dfrac{x_1-\frac{17}{2}}{-\frac1{\sqrt2}}=\dfrac{y_1-\frac{17}{2}}{\frac1{\sqrt2}}=\pm \sqrt{r^2+\frac1{\sqrt2}}$$

Now using $B$, I found $OB$, then using it, I found $OA$

$$OB=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{17}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{r^2}{2}+\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}}\\OA=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{17}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{3r^2}{2}+\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}}$$

I am struck. I can't calculate all the individual lengths of tangents and take their mean. There must be another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $O(0,0)$, $P(8,8)$ and $Q(9,9)$ are collinear.

By the [tangent-secant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent%E2%80%93secant_theorem) or the power of point theorem, at point $O$,

$$\begin{align*}
OA^2 &= OP \cdot OQ\\
&= 8\sqrt2 \cdot 9\sqrt 2\\
&= 144\\
OA &= 12
\end{align*}$$

So the length of each tangent is $12$, regardless of the radius.

Answer (score 1):

If I continue with your method, it's possible if I make two corrections on how you applied Pythagoras' theorem:

Firstly in $\triangle BDQ$, about the length $BD$, which should instead satisfy:

$$\begin{align*}
BD^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2 &= r^2\\
BD &= \sqrt{r^2 -\frac{1}{2}}\\
\end{align*}$$

So the length of $OB$ obtained from your method should be:

$$\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \frac{17}{2} \mp \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{2} -\frac{1}{2\cdot2}}\\
y_1 &= \frac{17}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{2} -\frac{1}{2\cdot2}}\\
OB &= \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2}\\
&= \sqrt{2\left[\left(\frac{17}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{r^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2\cdot2}\right]}\\
&= \sqrt{2\left(\frac{17}{2}\right)^2 + r^2 - \frac{1}{2}}\\
\end{align*}$$

Secondly in $\triangle OAB$, $\angle A$ is right-angled, not $\angle B$ as in your attempt. So

$$\begin{align*}
OA^2 + r^2 &= OB^2\\
OA &= \sqrt{\left[2\left(\frac{17}{2}\right)^2 + r^2 - \frac{1}{2}\right] - r^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{17^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{18\cdot 16}{2}}\\
&= 12
\end{align*}$$

So the length of each tangent is $12$, regardless of the radius.